# PHP Mail - Japanese characters are not displaying properly on Thunderbird

Tags: php, email, character, thunderbird

So I guess the title says it all. I've created a page with PHP with a form for visitors to fill up and send. But I'm having trouble with Japanese characters (or maybe even others) wherein the characters appear broken when viewed in Thunderbird (but the characters look fine on Gmail).

Is there a code or something for me to add on my PHP code so that the characters can be automatically be fixed when viewed on Thunderbird without going to any settings in Thunderbird? Thanks!